# Excel date format with abbreviated month without the dot

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, cell-format

Hi,

I am using this formula for custom date format in Excel:

```
[$-es-ES]d-mmm-yyyy
```

and this is what I get:

```
4-oct.-2018
```

almost fine but I dont need that dot there, how can I lose it?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a potential regional settings issue in your operating system.

Comment: What does the actual data input look like?

Comment: Its actually a problem with Spanish data format and it doesnt happen in other languages but I need the format in Spanish. The data looks like this 10/4/18.

Comment: You can apply this `[$-0C0A] d- mmmm -yyyy' will show  `4- octubre -2018`.

Comment: Just to make things even more confusing, when I apply your format on my system to a date, it does not come out with a period.  but the reported date is completely wrong from what I entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use either of the Custom Date Format:**

```
[$-"es-ES"]d-mmm-yyyy

[$-"es-US"]d-mmm-yyyy
```

You get `4-Oct-2018`.

Comment: when you put in his formula on your system do you get a period?

Comment: @ForwardEd, No Period,, Date will looks exactly like I've shown, I've posted my answer after the Format has been applied. ☺

Comment: Oh, that one works like a charm, although the first letter is nt capitalized on my end. Thank you!

Comment: @ Cain remember to test Decembre

Comment: Glaad to help you @CainNuke keep asking.

Comment: I tested, it works alright but without the quotes.

Comment: @CainNuke, without  Quotes it may spoil Month may be you get `AUG` for `OCT`,  so I would recommend better use Quotes! ☺